# Is it appropriate to use AtomicReference with a java lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, atomicreference

I often find myself using this idiom:

```
AtomicReference<MyCoolObject> coolReference = new AtomicReference(new MyCoolObject());

getOptionalValue().ifPresent(presentValue -> {
  coolReference.set(new MyCoolObject(presentValue));
});
return coolReference.get();
```

Is this a bad habit, or a legitimate use of `AtomicReference`?

Comment: What's the point? Why do you need an atomic reference?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that construct?

Comment: FYI, an alternative using method references: `getOptionalValue().map(MyCoolObject::new).ifPresent(coolReference::set)`

Comment: Better `return getOptionalValue().map(MyCoolObject::new).orElseGet(MyCoolObject::new);`

Comment: @shmosel, Because I can't return the new `MyCoolObject` inside the lambda.

Comment: @fabian This looks like a pretty nice alternative.